# Stop p tags from automatically adding in Wordpress - Twig, ACF and filter shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, strip-tags, auto-populating

Wordpress is adding p tags automatically when i wrap my code with {% filter shortcodes %} {% endfilter %}. Is there anyway i can disable this because i have to use the filter shortcodes code. I am using Twig and Advanced Custom Fields so the_content is not going to work for me.

Here is what i tried in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_unneeded_silly_p_tags_from_shortcodes');
function remove_unneeded_silly_p_tags_from_shortcodes($the_content){
    $array = array (
        '<p>['      => '[', //replace "<p>[" with "["
        ']</p>'     => ']', //replace "]</p>" with "]"
        ']<br />'   => ']' //replace "]<br />" with "]"
    );
    $the_content = strtr($the_content, $array); //replaces instances of the keys in the array with their values
    return $the_content;
}

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 99);
remove_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Please help!!